# Is it possible run selenium test with input data in excel?

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I use Selenium Web Driver in Eclipse with JUnit. I compose my main test  - common for all other, on the begining I set my input data (which is different for each test):

```
String update_f="//*[@id='columnTitle2']/input";
String update_u="dscr";
String name_p="Test";
String[] link=new String [] {"001","01"};
String[] lov_name= new String [] {"Work","Machine"};
```

Is it possible to set this data in excel file and than just change this file if I want execute specific test (actually set specific data)?

Comment: [See this.](https://www.google.com/search?q=java%20read%20from%20xls) Therefore, try [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) or [Lars Vogel's Java Excel API](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaExcel/article.html).

Answer (score 0):

It is possible my friend,with the help some external jars to handle Excel spread sheets.

U can choose
a. JXL Jar ( which is easy to use and is sufficient for normal functionalities like read and write) - http://www.andykhan.com/jexcelapi/tutorial.html
b. Apache poi jar - http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2003/04/16/poi_excel.html

- Add these external jars into eclipse.
- create an excel file with different input values.
- Read and pass these values from excel through the jars.

currently im working with JXL it is good.